# IIS 8.5 php Version 7.3.11 64 UPLOAD BIGGER THAN 2GB?

Tags: php, iis, maxrequestlength, upload-max-filesize

I'm trying to upload a file of 4 GB or more file (sum 5GB) files - 500 Internal server error!!!
Any idea?

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

system.web > HttpRuntime > maxRequestLength 5079040 (KB)

PHP I'VE TRIED:

post_max_size = 0
upload_max_filesize = 0

post_max_size = 5G
upload_max_filesize = 4G

post_max_size = 5120M
upload_max_filesize = 4096M

It works untill 2GB
All the other: 500 - internal error.

nothing in logs

Answer (score 0):

iis has its own limit to upload the file which is 2 GB.

But you can try the below workaround to upload the larger file with iis site:

1. Set ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes in php.ini file
2. Set iis application pool idle time out to 0

[image]

3. Increase iis site connection time-out value:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your replay, but I am using the application inside the 1GB LAN it takes less than 60 seconds to output 500 internal error